# How can you determine the number of reference frames in h.264 video using libavcodec

Tags: video

I'd like to determine the number of reference frames used in encoding a h.264 file using libavcodec. I've been able to determine most of the other information I'm looking for programmatically but so far can't locate this one item.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to find the max ref frames count in a given h.264 stream, produced by an unknown encoder?  (mediainfo shows a ref frame count even when it doesn't find x264's version/settings string).  To find the max DPB size, I guess?  Or are you talking about how to find out what x264 settings libavcodec passed to libx264 when your program is encoding?  x264's logging to stdout includes a histogram of usage for each ref distance.

Answer (score 0):

4-5 reference frames are recommend for general encoding. Higher values will only add to encoding time and decoding complexity, with little to no gain in quality.